# Is there a way for a celery task to determine whether the worker is waiting for it to finish so it can shut down?

Tags: python, celery

We have a few celery tasks that are really long running (and no, we can't segment it out in to subtasks, unfortunately) but are totally safe to kill mid task.

This sucks when we need to deploy new code because when we need to bounce all the workers if one of those is in play then it can take half an hour instead of 30 seconds.

Is there any way from within a task to find out if it's worker is waiting on it so that it can terminate/restart/whatever so that these tasks that are safe to kill can periodically check that and self terminate?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way I've found to do this (works in celery 5.3.6):

```py
import celery

from your_app.celery import app


def my_task_is_still_active():
    task_id = celery.current_task.request.id

    active_task_ids = {
        task["id"]
        for tasks in (app.control.inspect().active() or {}).values()
        for task in tasks
    }

    return task_id in active_task_ids
```

Docs for [`current_task`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.current_task) and [`app.control.inspect()`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/3.1/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Inspect).

Testing locally this seems to work well with this task:

```py
@shared_task
def my_task():
    import time
    for ii in range(30):
        if not my_task_is_still_active():
            logger.info("Task no longer active!")
            break

        logger.info("Task still active, sleeping...")
        time.sleep(1)
```

After Ctrl-C'ing the worker executing this task we see

```
2024-03-20 16:46:10,642 INFO     Task still active, sleeping...
^C
worker: Hitting Ctrl+C again will terminate all running tasks!

worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
2024-03-20 16:46:12,651 INFO     Task no longer active!
2024-03-20 16:46:12,655 INFO     Task utils.tasks.my_task[5dbb25ea-5fa3-48f1-8c6f-83e51a940609] succeeded in 9.1200849559973s: None
```